# Parameter modification in a url with a proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua, proxypass

I have an url like this:
  http://test1.com/_a/client/#/room/!zzz:test2.com

I would like to replace this prameter `test2.com`with an IP address and a port like this:

```
http://test1.com/_a/client/#/room/!zzz:192.x.x.x:80
```

How can I do that with nginx?
Here's what I did:

```
location /_a/client/#/room/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/_a/client/#/room/!zzz:192.x.x.x:80;
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You can't do this in `nginx`. The fragment (part of the URL from the `#` onwards) is never sent to the `nginx` server.

Answer (score 0):

No web server or proxy ever sees the `#` in a URL, or anything that follows it, because browsers don't send this part of the URL, which is called the *fragment*.

These are accessible only to the browser.  They aren't sent to the server, so it is impossible to modify them there.